# How to check that the support of a complete linear system, of divisors is dense?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a projective variety and $L=|\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)|$ is a complete linear system. How to chack that the support of $L,$ that is $\bigcup_{F\in L} F$ is dense in $X$? For example, if $X=Bl_{p}\mathbb{P}^{2},$ $L=|\mathcal{O}_{X}(H-E)|,$ where $H$ is the pull back of the generic line in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and $E$ is the exceptional line, is the support of $L$ dense?

Is there a criterion for telling if the generic element is irreducible? in this case it is because it can only be the union of lines, but how about in general (for instance, higher dimension) ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. As soon as $h^0(L)\geq 2$, there is an element of $|L|$ passing through any point of $X$, so if I understand correctly your definition the "support" is $X$? And of course if $h^0(L)=1$ it is the only effective divisor in $|L|$, hence not dense.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, maybe it is too basic but is it just the map $\phi_{|L|}:X\to\mathbb{P}(|L|)$ ? How about irreducibility of a general member of the linear system?

Comment: See [Bertini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_Bertini). The question would indeed be more appropriate on MSE.

Comment: Thx abx, it really helped.